# how to send object from html ng-repeat to js function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting data from db and put it in a scope, then iterate on these data by ng-repeat in html.
what i am trying to do is to send the selected object when the user check on a checkbox to get another data based on an id for example . i tried to use ng-model and ng-change on the checkbox but it sends only true or false .

HTML

```
<div id="frame" class="widget-content" style="height:50vh; overflow:auto;">
    <table  style="font-size: 12px;display: inline-block;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Check</th>
                <th>Group Code</th>
                <th>Group Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="g in Groups | unique : 'Group_code'"
                ng-click="showInEdit(g)"
                ng-class="{selected:g === selectedRow}">
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="g"
                           ng-true-value="g" ng-change="Getrequest2(g)"/>
                <td>{{g.Group_code}}</td>
                <td>{{g.group_name_latin}}</td>**
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table  style="font-size: 12px; float: left;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Check</th>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="i in items | unique : 'Item_code'"
                ng-click="showInEdit(i)"
                ng-class="{selected:i === selectedRow}">
                <td><input type="checkbox" />
                <td>{{i.Item_code}}</td>
                <td>{{i.ITEM_NAME_LATIN}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

angularjs

```
$scope.Getrequest1 = function (g) {
    //console.log(g);
    $scope.typecd = g.TypeCode;
    $scope.ShowLoading('slow');
    LOASrv.GetGroup("LOAApprovalSetup/GetGroup" +
                    "?typ=" + g.TypeCode +
                    '&hospid=' + $scope.hospitalid + 
                    '&userky=' + $scope.userkey
    ).then(function (response) {
        $scope.Groups = (response.data);
        $scope.HideLoading('slow');
    })
}

$scope.Getrequest2 = function (i) {
    console.log(i);
    $scope.ShowLoading('slow');
    LOASrv.GetItem("LOAApprovalSetup/GetItem" + 
                   "?typ=" + $scope.typecd + 
                   '&hospid=' + $scope.hospitalid + 
                   '&userky=' + $scope.userkey +
                   '&groupcd=' + i
    ).then(function (response) {
        $scope.items = (response.data);
        $scope.HideLoading('slow');
    })
}
```

Comment: The HTML, has `ng-change="Getrequest2(g)"` but the JS has `$scope.Getrequest2 = function (i)`. It looks like the code is passing an object to a function that expects a string.

Comment: Thanks for replying , kindly how to solve it? to receive object

Comment: in the onchange event of your checkbox, from your html you can pass the ID or the code that you need to make another api call. your onchange should be like ng-change="Getrequest2(g.Group_code)" .   assuming group_code is the code for each object that you need to pass in the 2nd api call.

Answer (score 0):

You’re assigning ‘g’ object to checkbox ng-model.

This changes the value of ‘g’ from object to boolean on checkbox select.

That’s why you’re getting true/false

Change `ng-model=“g.someBooleanName”` and try